# Custom Shape with tcolorbox/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm trying to make a custom rectangle to surround my section headers. It's a regular rectangle with the upper-left and lower-right corners "cut" so they're diagonal.

I want it to look like this: [image: pic]

I tried to modify the long example from tcolorbox pages 201–202, but am only getting missing corners.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[13pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9in, paperheight=6in, margin=0.3in, marginparwidth=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter, colbacktitle=white, colback=white, coltitle=black, width=.5\linewidth}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north west)
--([xshift=5mm]frame.north west)--(frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
--([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle;}]
Sample Text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

But it's looking like this: [image: error picture]

Can anyone help me figure out why it's not drawing correctly? Or should I be using something else and not tcolorbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, the frame is drawn correctly but a white rectangle is then filled above the frame, obscuring the corners. Try a colour other than `white` to see what is happening more easily.

Do you want something like this?

[image: sample box]

If so, you have to hide the `interior` of the box or else it is placed above the frame, with regular corners. So the `fill` is passed to the TiKZ command instead and `interior hidden` is used to block the standard filling of the frame.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9in, paperheight=6in, margin=0.3in, marginparwidth=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \tcbset{
    nobeforeafter,
    colbacktitle=white,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    coltext=white,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
    width=.5\linewidth,
  }

  \begin{tcolorbox}
    [
      enhanced,
      interior hidden,
      frame code={
        \path [tcb fill frame] (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([yshift=5mm]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east) -- cycle;
      },
    ]
    Sample Text
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

You might want to look at the options for `sharp corners` in the package manual, too, in case that offers something easier.